# Specialised Boxplot: Plotting Lines to the Error Bars to Highlight the Data Range in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, boxplot

**Overview**

I have a data frame called **ANOVA.Dataframe.1 (see below)** containing the **dependent variable** called 'Canopy_Index', and the **independent variable** called 'Urbanisation_index".

My aim is to produce a boxplot **(exactly the same as the desired result below)** for **Canopy Cover (%)** for each category of the **Urbanisation Index** with plotted lines pointing towards both the bottom and top of the error bars to highlight the data range.

I have searched intensively in order to find the code to produce the desired boxplot this **(please see the desired result)**, but I was unsuccessful, and I'm also unsure if these boxplots have a specialised name.

Perhaps this can be achieved in either **ggplot** or **Base R**

If anyone can help, I would be deeply appreciative.

**Desired Result** ( [Reference](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.536445!/file/MASH_ANOVA_in_R.pdf))

[image]

I can produce an ordinary boxplot with the R-code below, but I cannot figure out how to implement the lines pointing towards the ends of the error bars.

**R-code**

```
Boxplot.obs1.Canopy.Urban<-boxplot(ANOVA.Dataframe.1$Canopy_Index~ANOVA.Dataframe.1$Urbanisation_index,
                               main="Mean Canopy Index (%) for Categories of the Urbansiation Index",
                               xlab="Urbanisation Index",
                               ylab="Canopy Index (%)")
```

**Boxplot produced from R-code**

[image]

**Data frame 1**

```
structure(list(Urbanisation_index = c(2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4), Canopy_Index = c(65, 75, 55, 85, 85, 85, 95, 85, 
85, 45, 65, 75, 75, 65, 35, 75, 65, 85, 65, 95, 75, 75, 75, 65, 
75, 65, 75, 95, 95, 85, 85, 85, 75, 75, 65, 85, 75, 65, 55, 95, 
95, 95, 95, 45, 55, 35, 55, 65, 95, 95, 45, 65, 45, 55)), row.names = c(NA, 
-54L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Dataframe 2**

```
structure(list(Urbanisation_index = c(2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
), Canopy_Index = c(5, 45, 5, 5, 5, 5, 45, 45, 55, 15, 35, 45, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 35, 15, 15, 25, 25, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 25, 
15, 35, 25, 45, 5, 25, 5, 5, 5, 5, 55, 55, 15, 5, 25, 15, 15, 
15, 15)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alice, is this what you are looking for?

[image]

You can do everything with `ggplot2`, but for non standard things you have to play with it for a while. My code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr)

df %.>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(
    x = Urbanisation_index,
    y = Canopy_Index,
    group = Urbanisation_index
  )) +
  stat_boxplot(
    geom = 'errorbar',
    width = .25
  ) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_line(
    data = group_by(., Urbanisation_index) %>%
      summarise(
        bot = min(Canopy_Index),
        top = max(Canopy_Index)
      ) %>%
      gather(pos, val, bot:top) %>% 
      select(
        x = Urbanisation_index,
        y = val
      ) %>%
      mutate(gr = row_number()) %>%
      bind_rows(
        tibble(
          x = 0,
          y = max(.$y) * 1.15,
          gr = 1:8
        )
      ),
    aes(
      x = x,
      y = y,
      group = gr
    )) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(
    xlim = c(min(.$Urbanisation_index) - .5, max(.$Urbanisation_index) + .5),
    ylim = c(min(.$Canopy_Index) * .95, max(.$Canopy_Index) * 1.05)
  ) +
  ylab('Company Index (%)') +
  xlab('Urbanisation Index')
```

Comment: Hey Pawel, This is amazing! Thank you! Absolutely Yes! This is exactly what I wanted. Could I please ask for some further advice, In total, I have two of these plots to produce. I tried this code on a different dataset to produce the second plot. However, the boxes are half visible at the bottom of the plot and the rest is not visible. I placed the second data frame in the data section. Could I please ask which section of the code needs manipulating to fix this issue? Many thanks if you can help.

Comment: Alice, it was `ylim` part in `coord_cartesian`. Now I've put there multiplied minimum and maximum of `Canopy_Index` so it will work with any dataset. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code is wonderful! I really appreciate your help

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help :)